# how to get multiple rows from multiple tables concatenated into a single string in a stored procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-11g

I have a table A that has 7 different 1-N relationships. Given an A id, now I am running 7 simple queries to get the N side rows. I suspect this could be sped up.

Is it possible to:

- create a stored procedure, with only input the A id
- the sp runs the 7 queries, at each step concatenating the result to a single string. Rows/Columns should be separated in some way to allow automatic parsing later (not sure what is the best practice here)
- the sp returns the single string, and in my code I only do a round-trip to Oracle

Is this possible? Is my gut right that this would be faster? Any pointers?

thanks

Comment: Please provide table definition with sample data and the expected output, and if you have the query to get the output but not sufficient then include that query as well.

Comment: I cannot provide  the DDL for the table. But it is not critical, what I want to get feedback on is whether the approach will be more performant that doing the 7 queries from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to concatenate multiple rows and columns into a single string, just to parse it later. Overhead 1.

Next, you want to write PL/SQL for something that can be easily done in plain SQL. Overhead 2.

Something like this (I just used random views for the 7 data source):

```
select listagg(x, '|') within group (order by null) from
(
  select 'COL11' || '-' || 'COL12' as x from v$database where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL21' || '-' || 'COL22'      from v$instance where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL31' || '-' || 'COL32'      from v$logfile  where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL41' || '-' || 'COL42'      from v$log      where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL51' || '-' || 'COL52'      from v$datafile where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL61' || '-' || 'COL62'      from v$tempfile where rownum = 1 union all
  select 'COL71' || '-' || 'COL72'      from v$version  where rownum = 1
);
```

You want to minimize round trips. You do not need all this hassle for that, you can fetch multiple rows at a time.

Comment: thanks, I'll try this. Parsing on the string will happen much later (it might not even happen for many instances), in a place and in a way where it will not be a perf issue.  Also I did not give the whole context of this: I have a given system, I don't have the source code, I am only given a way to tweak the sql calls that it does. And I have several constraints on what those sql can produce. So I am pretty sure running all sql in oracle an save many roundtrips will pay off.